# Did one Sherry Michaels lose her daughter to COVID-19 and then use it to make anti-mask posts on Facebook?

Tags: covid-19, facebook

Saw this alleged screenshot from Facebook posted to Twitter.

[image]

The account and the group are both real. However I have not been able to find the post, although it may have been deleted or I may be inept.

The comment suggests it may be real though, as does another screen grab apparently from the thread

[image]

Even then, it might be fake information from a troll account. I find it hard to believe a real family could be such horrific ghouls.

At least I hope so. Would appreciate knowing to put my mind at rest.

Comment: I'm missing how this is notable.

Comment: I don't want to use my veto to reopen this, but I would argue it is notable. The original post and the reaction of the Internet has been widespread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original account holder has [now posted a confession](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=646794889552359&set=a.116752239223296&type=3) that the identity (Sherry Michaels) and the story associated with it was a lie. They claimed it was some sort of political experiment.

> I would like to share some information regarding an earlier post from this account. I would like to begin by clarifying that indeed there is no Sherry Michaels and no Natylee Michaels. The post was an attempt to test the beliefs of this community and bring light to the toxicity that exists on “Colleyville Citizens Opposed to High Density” that is perpetuated by not only citizens of the Colleyville community, but also members of the city council.

Answer (score 16):

Found [this post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1091015987575851/permalink/3425276964149730/) by a local councillor on the [Colleyville Citizens Opposed To High Density](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1091015987575851/about/) Facebook group.

> I’ve had many text and emails asking me if there was a death in
> Colleyville due to a recent post.
>
> NO. There has not been any death in Colleyville related to covid. I
> tried looking up the posters name and address but have not had such
> luck with any info.
>
> To play a political game with what could be a fake profile scaring
> people about a recent death is despicable. I’m sorry it has come down
> to this type of nastiness from folks to slant a point of view. ￼
>
> This looks to be highly suspicious and if it’s true we with the city
> would like to meet with you.
>
> Thanks

Comment: This needs a link. Otherwise we are playing a game of "Which one is the troll?"

Comment: @Oddthinking - You can find it by searching for the group on FB.  I felt it was inappropriate to copy the poster's name without permission.

Comment: It turns out the poster is a local politician. I think linking words to his profile are fair game.

Comment: So, Sherry Michaels does not live in Colleyville, and her daughter did not die in Colleyville.  But the posts in question did not make either of those claims.

Comment: @Gedgar: The Sherry Michaels account posted to "Colleyville Citizens Opposed To High Density". It's not unreasonable to think that she was posing as a local. I agree it could be an out, where it turns out she is authentic but not local.